# Laravel Eloquent with condition

Tags: laravel, if-statement, eloquent, conditional-statements, switch-statement

### **Can anyone help me ?**

I have eloquent like this

```
$data = DocumentFile::with(['document_folder', 'document_request.user.profile'])
        ->where('isactive', true)
        ->when($request->search, function($query, $search) {
                $query->where('name', 'ilike', '%'.$search.'%');
        })
        ->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')
        ->paginate($paginate)
```

But it doesn't show the data what I want.

---

### I have 3 models like this:

- **DocumentFolder**, Fields: id, name
- **DocumentFile**, Fields: id, name, is_private, is_active, created_by, updated_at, document_folder_id
- **DocumentRequest**, Fields: id, user_id, document_file_id

**1 DocumentFolder** has many **DocumentFile**, and **1 DocumentFile** has many **DocumentRequest**

---

### **I wanna show data with conditions:**

1. If **DocumentFile** *is _active = true*, show it, if *is _active = false* don't
2. If **DocumentFile** *is_private = false* show it
3. If **DocumentFile** *is_private = true*, must be check to **DocumentRequest** the user id from auth login has on **DocumentRequest**, if yes show it, if no don't
4. If user login has *user_id* on *created_by* from **DocumentFile**, if yes show it
5. Data can be searched by **DocumentFile** *name*
6. Data ordered by *updated_at => DESC* from **DocumentFile**
7. Paginate **DocumentFile**

Answer (score 0):

check [logical grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#logical-grouping) for query

```php
$data = DocumentFile::with(['document_folder', 'document_request.user.profile'])
  ->where(function($query){
    $query->where('id_active', true) // 1
      ->orWhere('id_private', false) // 2
      ->orWhere('created_by', auth()->user()->id); // 3 and 4
  })
  ->when($request->search, function($query, $search) {
      $query->where('name', 'ilike', '%'.$search.'%');
    })
    ->orderByDesc('updated_at')
    ->paginate($paginate);
```